# Using polygonizer to convert raster to shapefile in R

Tags: raster, r, polygonize

From https://ghsl.jrc.ec.europa.eu/download.php?ds=pop I have downloaded a .TIF file, that I am trying to convert into a .SHP file using R. I have loaded the file in R (as `italy_raster` and am trying to use the `polygonizer` function (as outlined here https://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/ and here https://gist.github.com/Pakillo/c6b076eceb0ef5a70e3b).

However, when I use the function (after some time), I receive an error message:

```
polygonizer(italy_raster)
```

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding,
>   use_iconv = use_iconv,  :    Cannot open data source

I've spent some time trying to figure out what might be the issue, but I am quite new to R and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Use isoband package, there's a wrapper for raster objects to return sf polygons here: https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/1ba2f7906b692deb29bcfa67bb9854cf

Comment: The population files are pretty much continuous maps of population, so any polygonising is going to try and make each pixel a polygon. Why are you doing that? Usually you'd polygonise a raster that was made up of large clearly-defined areas.